# How to mock KafkaAdminClient

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to do a unit test for the code below. I am able to test the exception block but unable to test the below block as I am getting an exception.

How can I mock or set values to the `ListTopicsResult topics = client.listTopics()`, so that the flow goes into the `if` block?

> `if(!topics.names.get().isEmpty()) { response  = true; }`

```
public boolean isBrokerRunning() {
    boolean response = false;
    Properties property = new Properties();
    
    try(AdminClient client = KafkaAdminClient.create(property)) {
        ListTopicsResult topics = client.listTopics();
        if(!topics.names.get().isEmpty()) {
            response = true;
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        response = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get any help on this? can you share how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

```
KafkaAdminClient.create
```

This is a static function call, so you need to mock static function, You can use **powermockit** on top of **mockito** to mock static functions.

[see this example](https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock-static)

Answer (score 0):

use [mockito-inline](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline) can do this. need some trick

```
  @Test
  public void mockCreateAdmin() {
    AdminClient mock = mock(KafkaAdminClient.class);
    try (MockedStatic<Admin> staticMock = mockStatic(Admin.class)) {
      staticMock.when(() -> Admin.create(any(Properties.class))).thenReturn(mock);
      KafkaAdminClient adminClient = (KafkaAdminClient) KafkaAdminClient.create(new Properties());
      // when
      
      // then
      assertEquals(mock, adminClient);
    }
  }
```